# Controling Clones through Protein Deletion

Tags: science-based, biology, science-fiction

I have a clone army.  One of the measures I use to control this clone army is a missing gene needed for synthesis of a protein.  They remain loyal, they receive the protein, they continue to live.

I am concerned that the clones will undergo further genetic engineering to add back in the missing / modified gene.  Is it possible to set up some form of pleiotropy (a gene influences two unrelated phenotypes) or a cluster of pleiotropy -- something alone the lines of you correct the ability to manufacture the protein and you end up with severe genetic disease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Not really, no

Something as simple as manufacturing a protein?  Manufacturing a protein is pretty basic machinery.  The [enzymes used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aminoacyl_tRNA_synthetase) to read the gene and build the protein operate one amino acid at a time.  They will just continue to do their work.

If your adversary inserts the gene for this protein, it will just start getting made.  You have simply disabled the gene that makes this protein, rather than make the protein toxic - because the person still needs this protein and the whole idea is to have a dead hand switch in the form of supplying it.

You probably would need to engineer a new enzyme, or complex of enzymes, that form a novel biochemical pathway.  It would detect when that protein - and only that protein - was being synthesised, and sabotage its host body.

But that's just the opening salvo in this arms race.

## The halting problem

#### or, How I learned to stop worrying and reverse engineer the detector

The general proof behind the impossibility of solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is applicable in a wide range of contexts.  In a nutshell, 'foolproof `foo` detectors' always have a problem when `foo`es have access to the detector.  They can simply study the detector, and find a way to force it to go awry.

In general, given any `foo` I can write a detector to find other `bars` that look just like the `foo`.  And given any detector, I can write a `foo` the detector will misfire on when ideally I wish it wouldn't.

So it will be here.  You already went through the first two iterations of this idea yourself: The control mechanism, and the initial bypass (which was designed by reverse engineering the control mechanism).

Yes, you can always research counter-bypass modifications to the gene stock.  And for awhile, it'll work.  But then you'll find yourself needing to research counter-(counter-bypass-bypass-) modifications.

## Game theory

All is not lost, though.  Even though, in theory, it's impossible to create something that cannot be beaten, period... If you mess with the incentives enough, you can make it not cost-effective.

If you put in enough different barriers and levels of tamper-resistance, you can make it so expensive to research a counter measure that it's just not worth it.  Each countermeasure probably requires complex genetic engineering, to make failsafes and then rework existing metabolic pathways to involve (and thus require the presence of) said failsafes (so simply removing them will kill the patient).

None of this engineering is going to be cheap.  The economics probably favor the attacker (the one who wants to bypass your mechanism) because it's easier to break something than it is to build it.

But the game theory might still be enough to tilt the economics your way.  You just need to keep the number of disgruntled clone soldiers small enough that someone doesn't see the ROI for unshackler research turn positive.